# Test ran a free template on VS2019 causes white borders on the left and right side

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, visual-studio-2019

people of Stackoverflow

Ive been stuck for almost a day now because of this. I would like to know if any of you have the solution for the problem im currently facing.

**What I did:**

1) downloaded a free bootstrap template

2) copy, pasted and included all necessary files in Visual Studio 2019

3) linked up all css files, js files and image files

4) clean and build the solution.

Then this appears:
[White borders, on the left and right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zuyD.jpg)

Whereas when I opened the original file, everything looks normal as it should be:
[Normal looking site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHB8U.jpg)

Any one has this problem ? Because I have not touched, edited any codes besides linking up the respective files.

Comment: Do you know how to use `git`? Create a git repo with the working files, `commit`. Replace working files with the non-working one and see the difference between the two on the `changes`.

Comment: Most likely the VS uses a different rendering engine (such as that of the IE) other than the browser you're trying to view the website in.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh . Hi thx for responding. Nope . I have no idea how to use that. Its my first time, but Ill learn it up  ASAP.

Comment: @AkshitMehra When building the files on VS, it opens up Google Chrome .(and shows that white border)

When i clicked on the original file that was extracted from the zip, a beautiful normal looking index page is shown. (opened on google chrome as well)